# How to replace div when hover but without change other div

Tags: html, css

I want make a page where I have 8 boxes with divs, and when I hover a div this div is replaced to another but without affecting others. I know I could make 8 orders classifying each div but I want a simple css order to do it to all divs. So when I hover div 1 .p.e this div is replaced with another div but div 2-8 does not change until I hover it too.

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFB273;

}

div[class="a"] {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FF7373;
    width: 280px;
    height: 420px;
    border: 5px solid #6C8AD5;
    margin: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
div[class="b"] {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #6C8AD5;
    width: 280px;
    height: 420px;
    margin: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.price {
font-weight:bold;
text-align: center;
}  
.a:hover {
 display: none;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="a" id="a1">
        
    </div>



    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="a" id="a2">
        
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: needed more explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want like this Please see the below code

```css
    body {
  background-color: #FFB273;

}
.a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FF7373;
    width: 280px;
    height: 420px;
    border: 5px solid #6C8AD5;
    margin: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
.b {
     display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #6C8AD5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
.a:hover > .b{
 display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   
    <div class="a" id="a1">
         <div class="b"></div>
    </div>



   
    <div class="a" id="a2">
         <div class="b"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: YES, it is exactly like I want, thank you very much!

Comment: There are just one problem, when I write something inside divs and then I hover boxes, it deconfigure. Can it be solved?

Comment: I'm not understand what you want to say but  i think  you  want to display text on hover

Comment: No problem I already solved it, thank you a lot btw for  what you teach me!